# How do I get the name of the file NLog is writing to?

Tags: nlog

I am writing an application that will be utilized by members of our operations group.  I'd like to show on the screen, the name of the file that NLog is writing to.  This will allow them to view the file if necessary.

I could hard code the name, but I'd like to allow the NLog.config file to be used instead.  I'd like to be able to get the actual name of the file being written to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Between a few comments I found on the internet and reflecting on the assembly with Telerik JustDecompile, I was able to come up with this solution.

When I need the actual name of one of my targets, I can just call the method below like this

```
string fileName = GetLogFileName("file");
```

where file is the name of my target in the nlog.config file

```
public string GetLogFileName(string targetName) {
    string rtnVal = string.Empty;

    if (LogManager.Configuration != null && LogManager.Configuration.GetConfiguredNamedTargets().Count != 0) {
        Target t  = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName(targetName);
        if(t != null){
            Layout layout = new Layout((t as NLog.Targets.FileTarget).FileName);
            rtnVal = layout.GetFormattedMessage(null);
        }
    }

    return rtnVal;
}
```

for the 2.1.0.0 release of NLog, I've had to change the code to this

```
public string GetLogFileName(string targetName) {
    string rtnVal = string.Empty;

    if (LogManager.Configuration != null && LogManager.Configuration.ConfiguredNamedTargets.Count != 0) {
        NLog.Targets.Target t = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName(targetName);
        if (t != null) {
            NLog.Layouts.Layout layout = (t as NLog.Targets.FileTarget).FileName;
            rtnVal = layout.Render(LogEventInfo.CreateNullEvent());
        }
    }

    return rtnVal;
}
```

Comment: The version of NLog that I'm using doesn't expose Layout.GetFormattedMessage, it's protected so this won't work. You have to call Render() instead and pass it a LogEventInfo object to work. If I nail down a good solution I'll post it as an answer for future reference. I can parse the filename but it isn't formatting correctly. For my needs it's working correctly though because I'm just trying to get the log directory it's logging to.

Answer (score 2):

you need to write a custom target

follow the instructions under [nlog-project.org/wiki/How_to_write_a_Target](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/How_to_write_a_Target)

then modify it to be an interceptor only and add the ActualLogfile property

```
[Target("Interceptor")]
public sealed class InterceptTarget : FileTarget
{
    public string ActualLogfile { get; set; } 

    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        ActualLogfile = this.FileName.Render(logEvent);
        string logMessage = this.Layout.Render(logEvent);
        base.Write(logEvent);
    }
}
```

NLog.config should be something like this:

```
<nlog>
  <targets>
    <target name="i" 
            xsi:type="Interceptor"
            fileName="${basedir}\logs\${shortdate}.log" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo="i"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

remark: be shure to generate a very early log message (at pgm start), before ActualLogFile is empty.

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply parse NLog.config for any/all <target>'s?

Comment: Because that doesn't give the real name when you've used variables for the filename (such as ${basedir}